# perl - create a json from decoded json

Tags: json, perl

This question might look stupid, but i have been spending hours on this. I'm not a perl expert. So I have a JSON-encoded string, which I decode with this:

```
$filters = decode_json $data;
$criteria = @{shift($filters)}{'criteria'};
```

I then process these filters and criteria and I want to get $data back in json format. So i simple want to reverse this code above. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: fyi, `$criteria = @{shift($filters)}{'criteria'};` should be `$criteria = ${shift($filters)}{'criteria'};`, and is more readable as `$criteria = shift($filters)->{'criteria'};`

Answer (score 1):

Is it not just

```
$data = encode_json $filters;
```

?

Comment: Shotor asked for a reversal of their code; I provided one. I phrased it in the form of a clarification because I'm not sure my assumptions are correct, but if they are, then it is also an answer.